File import not supported
Hey guys I've been having this problem for months where I go to import a file from my directory and it'll throw an error saying that the file can't be found, what's confusing though is that I can control click on the file that supposedly is not found and it will take me directly to it. Usually this error resolves itself by restarting VSCode but now for some reason I've run into this error again and it doesn't seem to go away. I'm also in a WSL environment to run Foundry if that makes any difference.
I have tried restarting VSCode. I have tried copying the relative path, I have tried copying the traditional path. Both of which still leave me able to control click on the file and be directed to file. But I'm still left with the error in my terminal saying Source"" not found: File import callback not supported.

Do you use VSCode remote for WSL?
Can you please add more valid tags to your question?
